# Is it possible to use Libtorch with VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, c++, g++

I have followed the instructions provided by Pytorch to installing C++ distributions of PyTorch:

https://pytorch.org/cppdocs/installing.html

However, this command produces an error:

```
cmake --build . --config Release
```

I have tried adjusting many things, and I always get an error. I am starting to wonder if it is even possible to do this with VS Code, or do I need to use Visual Studio (which I don't have and don't want to use) on my Windows instead. I say this because on Pytorch's GitHub:

https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch

They mention that "the build tools do not come with Visual Studio Code by default."

Based on the generated CMakeCache.txt file, the build system is ninja and the compiler is G++